# php shell : how to run code in existing file

Tags: php, shell

After launching the php shell

```
php -a
```

how do you run an existing php file say 'index.php'? I know it can be run like

`$php index.php`

from the command line. But how do you do it from the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just include it:

```php
include 'index.php';
```

Comment: on a high way too 5000

Comment: there you go again :)

Comment: @VihaanVerma Just tested it to be sure, and it definitely works! Maybe you're not calling it from the right directory?